# Using a 27" LED Cinema display with a 2009 Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, cinema-display, dvi

I have an old 2009 Macbook (white) and a 27" LED Cinema Display with a Mini DisplayPort cable. The Macbook only has a Mini DVI connector and I believe it's only single link (since it's not a Macbook Pro).

I would like to use the display with the Macbook. I don't care if the resolution is not the full 2560 by 1440 resolution of the Cinema Display.

There are several dual-link DVI to MiniDisplay port cables/boxes available (for example the *Atlona DVI to Mini DisplayPort Converter*) but they probably won't work because the connector on the Macbook is only single link (I believe).

There are also single link DVI to Mini DisplayPort converters available which will output an image at a maximum vertical resolution of 1200 but all of them specifically state that they **do not work** with 27" Cinema Displays.

The Cinema Display supports 2560 by 1440, 1920 by 1080, and 1280 by 720 resolutions and I would be fine with the 1920 by 1080 resolution. Is there a cable or converter that will allow me to do that?